# Which voltage source to use in PSpice?

Tags: voltage, parallel, series, pspice

I'm relatively new to using PSpice. I'm trying to copy over a circuit from an example I have in order to figure out the values across the resistors. I cannot figure out how to place a voltage point(without ground) on top of the circuit, with the ground on the bottom of the circuit. Which voltage component do I need to place on the top for this to work?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to attach a ground connection to the back of the voltage source. PSpice hates it when you leave floating connections. If you just attach a ground to the back of whatever voltage source you want it will simulate it just the same as if it was just a voltage source at the top. I'm assuming you are using DC, so type in VDC in part search to get the generic DC voltage source.